# UI doesn't change dynamically

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

When I ran the UI text changing script and the UI doesn't change, but in the inspector window I can see it changing.

If I tweak the settings a bit in the inspector it comes back.

And, sometimes the three UIs have been modified, sometimes the first and second ones, or sometimes only the first one ends up being modified.

Below is the code.

```cs
    using System. collections;
    
    //syncopation
    
    public Text result1;
    public Text result2;
    public Text result3;
    
    //name, rating, email variable declaration
    
    result1.text = "Name: " + name;
    result2.text = "Rating: " + rating;
    result3.text = "Email: " + email;
    
    //simplified
```

Tried: This script to change UI.

Goal: Change UI.

PS: I'm Korean, please understand that there are some sentences that I do not understand because I use a translator.

Comment: Could you paste full code of your method? Where you are updating text

Comment: Please post your complete code and how exactly it is executed. `And, there are cases in which three UIs have been modified, but the first and second ones, or only the first one, ends up being modified.` -> It sounds a bit like you might have dragged the wrong objects into your Inspector slots `result1` etc